# Place closest students as far as possible

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You are in charge of a classroom which has `n` seats in a single row, numbered `0` through `n-1`
During the day students enter and leave the classroom for the exam. 
In order to minimize the cheating, your task is to efficiently seat all incoming students.

You're given 2 types of queries: `add_student(student_id) -> seat index` and `remove_student(student_id) -> void`

The rules for seating the student is the following:

1. The seat must be unoccupied
2. The closest student must be as far away as possible
3. Ties can be resolved by choosing the lowest-numbered seat.

My Approach is to use Hashtable considering we have to assign seat index to each student which we can do using hash function. Is this approach correct?

If hashtable is the right approach then for - 'the closest student must be as far away as possible', how should I design efficient hash function?

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you're asking whether you can use a hashtable to store values associated with unique keys, then yes.  Yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like an interesting problem to me and so here is an algorithm that I have come up with, after giving it some thought.

So as the question says, it's only a single row numbered from 1 to n.

I was thinking of a greedy approach to this problem.

So here how it goes.

- Person coming first will be seated at 1.
- Person coming second will be seated at n, as this will create the farthest distance between them.
- Now we start keeping the subsets, so we have one subset as (1,n).
- Now when the third person comes in, he gets seated at mid of first subset i.e (1+n)/2. And after this we will have two subsets - (1,n/2) and (n/2,n).
- Now when the fourth person arrives he can either sit in the mid of (1,n/2) and (n/2,n).

And this flow will go on.

- Now suppose when a person leaves his seat and goes out of the class, then our subset range will change and then for the next incoming person, we will calculate new set of subsets for him.

Hope this helps. For this approach, I think an array of size n will also work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  This solution does not work because of the order the students can leave and open gaps.

So here's the solution I came up with.  I would create an initial position array.   So the position of the incoming student is just position[current_number_of_students-1].

Creating the array is the tricky part.

```
def position(number_of_chairs)
  # handle edge cases
  return [] if number_of_chairs.nil? || number_of_chairs <= 0
  return [0] if number_of_chairs == 1

  # initialize with first chair and the last chair
  @position = [0, number_of_chairs - 1]

  # We want to start adding the middle of row segments
  # but in the correct order.
  # The first segment is going to be the entire row
  @segments = [0, number_of_chairs - 1]

  while !@segments.empty?
    current_segment = @segments.shift
    mid = (current_segment[0] + current_segment[1]) / 2
    if (mid > current_segment[0] && mid < current_segment[1])
      @position << mid
      # add the bottom half to the queue
      @segments.push([current_segment[0], mid])
      # add the top half to the queue
      @segments.push([mid, current_segment[1]])
    end
  end

  @position
end
```